# Function print doesn't show the right format number in python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

After finishing the calculation I printed the result by using `print(data)`, but this is what I get:

`company     date        debit        credit        balance
 A           2017-09-30  185615790.0  1.123175e+10 -1.104614e+10
 B           2017-09-30  100539770.0  7.563231e+10 -7.553177e+10`

If I use function `to_excel` I can see the number with the right format but it's inconvenience to open an excel file every time I want to double check.

Comment: You should tell us what "the calculation", "the result", "the number" and "the right format" are. And I wonder why you are using floating-point for large financial numbers - they have limited accuracy.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I'm just using groupby.sum(). The right format should be:
`credit               balance
 11231752880       -11046137090
 75632314360       -75531774590`